# JSTL not rendering output in java 1.8 environment

Tags: jstl

I am having a wierd issue with one of our environments in processing Hashmap data using jstl.

The same data works well in other environments. I tried to output the hashmap data itself and can see that the key/value pair exists but as and when I am trying to output using jstl it is not. Its driving me nuts as QA/Local environment does render the data and not in the environment where I am seeking for. The only difference with other environments is Java 1.8 is being used in the issue environment.

tested that data is displayed in hidden field
data is

```
{districtProjectId=122, districtProjectIdentifier=abc 2FAP-1-2008 - Closed, calculatorSentToDistrict=2013-01-22 00:00:00.0, certificateExecution=2013-03-29 00:00:00.0, certificateReturnedFromDistrict=2013-03-25 00:00:00.0, certificateSentToDistrict=2013-03-05 00:00:00.0, consultantReview=null, firmCompletingReview=, firmReturn=null, schoolDistrictPhone=1231231233, treasurer=abc treasurer, treasurerEmail=test@testschools.com, paFirstName=Try, paLastName=Me, paFullName=Try Me, cmCompanyName=Try Construction, cmAddress=100 Detroit Ave-1495, cmCity=Lake, cmState=CA, cmZip=12122, cmFirstName=First, cmLastName=Try}" />
```

Here the issue is occurring only for couple of fields. Other fields (same type --string) are  being displayed correctly & consistently.

```
<c:forEach items="${report}" var="t3">

//no display at all
 <c:out value="${t3.paLastName}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.paFirstName}" /> 
 <c:out value="${t3.paLastName}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.paFullName}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.cmCompanyName}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.cmAddress}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.cmCity}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.firmCompletingReview}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.consultantReview}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.cmState}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.cmZip}" />
 <c:out value="${t3.cmFirstName}" />

//displays consistently
<c:out value="${t3.treasurer}" />
<c:out value="${t3.treasurerEmail}" />
</c:forEach>
```

All the fields are displayed perfectly in other environments.
- Using JSTLViewer from Controller
- Web.xml has 2.4 DTD mapping
- Tomcat version is same across all environments
- Java 1.8 is used in the specific environment where the issue is other's have 1.7

Any inputs please?

Comment: I believe I understood the issue.. the resultant List<Map> which I was sending to the front-end is after I merged two/three result sets based on a key match. That merge (using .putAll()) might be the issue where the underlying LinkedHashMap is having issue with 1.8; Hence though the hashmap is shown with the data, underlying Map.Entry might be with different hashCode/reference Class..my assumption :( THe EL is trying to read from one reference object only and hence only showing data which is from that particular Map within the list.

Comment: for (Map left : list) { //a map from one result set 
           ...some rule matching
            for (Map rightMap : other.getList()) { // a map from second result set
               Object rightKey = rightMap.get(other.getIdKey());
                if (leftKey.equals(rightKey)) {
                    if (other.hasMergeKey()) {
                        ....do some stuff here
                    } else {
                       left.putAll(rightMap); // though the addition shows end list ..underlying Map.Entry<> references are different ????
                    } } }  some logic within1.8